# How to tab within the description of a description list?

Tags: description, tabbing

Is there an easy solution to bring all paths after the HTTP method on the same vertical line?

```
\begin{description}
    \item[\texttt{GET \quad/}] Test
    \item[\texttt{GET /users/sign\_in}] Test
    \item[\texttt{POST /users/sign\_in}] Test
    \item[\texttt{DELETE /users/sign\_out}] Test
    \item[\texttt{GET /backend}] Test
    \item[\texttt{GET /backend/users}] Test
    \item[\texttt{POST /backend/users}] Test
    \item[\texttt{GET /backend/users/new}] Test
    ...
\end{description}
```

[image: Visualization of the problem]

Unfortunately I can't mix the tabbing environment with the description list. Is the description list the wrong element for doing this?

I also need everything in the normal text area of the page.

[image: asdada]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose two possible solutions, using `itemize` instead of `description`.

(1) move the path outside the item label (but you have to change font twice with `\fonttt{}`)

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item[\texttt{GET}]  \texttt{/} Test
    \item[\texttt{GET}]  \texttt{/users/sign\_in} Test
    \item[\texttt{POST}] \texttt{/users/sign\_in} Test
\end{itemize}
```

(2) if everything should be in mono type font, it is easier to use `\ttfamily` and then you don't need to use `\texttt{}` on each item.

```
\begin{itemize}\ttfamily
    \item[GET]  / Test
    \item[GET]  /users/sign\_in Test
    \item[POST] /users/sign\_in Test
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

**Edit:** using double backslashes to break lines.

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item[\texttt{GET}]  \texttt{/}\\ Test
    \item[\texttt{GET}]  \texttt{/users/sign\_in}\\ Test
    \item[\texttt{POST}] \texttt{/users/sign\_in}\\ Test
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}\ttfamily
    \item[GET]  /\\ Test
    \item[GET]  /users/sign\_in\\ Test
    \item[POST] /users/sign\_in\\ Test
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately the HTTP method is hanging out of the text area at the left side. This would break the document formatting convention I have to follow.

Comment: So, please, edit your code and put this kind of problem also. Let me tell you that you can format the `itemize` env. to change its margins, widths, etc...

Comment: I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think my solution using `tabto` will work for you, assuming your "Test" can wrap to the next line.  Perhaps the easiest solution is to use something like `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,preview,varwidth=true,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand\Mfmt[1]{\textbf{\textrm{#1}}}
\newcommand\longTest{This is a test, a longer test that wraps to two lines.}
\begin{document}
{\ttfamily
\begin{tabularx}{10cm}{lX}
  \Mfmt{GET}    & /                  \linebreak Test \\
  \Mfmt{GET}    & /users/sign\_in    \linebreak \longTest \\
  \Mfmt{POST}   & /users/sign\_in    \linebreak Test \\
  \Mfmt{DELETE} & /users/sign\_out   \linebreak Test \\
  \Mfmt{GET}    & /backend           \linebreak Test \\
  \Mfmt{GET}    & /backend/users     \linebreak Test \\
  \Mfmt{POST}   & /backend/users     \linebreak Test \\
  \Mfmt{GET}    & /backend/users/new \linebreak Test
\end{tabularx}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the solution using `tabto` that won't work with a long "Test":

```
\documentclass[12pt,preview,varwidth=true,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabto}
\newlength\ttl
\begin{document}
{\ttfamily
\settowidth\ttl{DELETE}
\begin{description}
    \item[GET]    \tabto{\ttl}/                  \tabto{\ttl} Test
    \item[GET]    \tabto{\ttl}/users/sign\_in    \tabto{\ttl} Test
    \item[POST]   \tabto{\ttl}/users/sign\_in    \tabto{\ttl} Test
    \item[DELETE] \tabto{\ttl}/users/sign\_out   \tabto{\ttl} Test
    \item[GET]    \tabto{\ttl}/backend           \tabto{\ttl} Test
    \item[GET]    \tabto{\ttl}/backend/users     \tabto{\ttl} Test
    \item[POST]   \tabto{\ttl}/backend/users     \tabto{\ttl} Test
    \item[GET]    \tabto{\ttl}/backend/users/new \tabto{\ttl} Test
\end{description}}
\end{document}
```

[image]